# Problems with stitching module opencv

Tags: opencv, image-stitching, opencv-stitching

I have been trying to use Stitching module of OpenCV for stitching images and for that purpose I started with an image and split it up with some overlap portion in both the images.

The stitching worked and I got the output.

But when I started experimenting with two images captured via camera, I started getting strange results.

> Removed some images, because can't match them or there are too similar images: (2).
> Try to decrease --match_conf value and/or check if you're stitching duplicates.
> Need more images

Tried changing the `match_conf` with no success and also tried with variations of the two input images.

Then just to experiment, I converted the images to another format (png -> jpg) and what I see is that the stitching module does not give the result and instead it gives the same problem as quoted above.

I compared the results obtained in the success and failure cases and I am not quite sure what is going wrong as the matches found in the image are almost same in both cases.

> Success case::
> Finding features...
> Features in image #1: 1327
> Features in image #2: 1176
> Finding features, time: 0.187466 sec
> Pairwise matching
> 1->2 matches: 156
> 1->2 & 2->1 matches: 213
> .Pairwise matching, time: 0.184411 sec...
>
> Failure case::
> Finding features...
> Features in image #1: 1326
> Features in image #2: 1180
> Finding features, time: 0.183571 sec
> Pairwise matching
> 1->2 matches: 151
> 1->2 & 2->1 matches: 207
> .Pairwise matching, time: 0.180866 sec...

Could some one please help me ?

Regards

Comment: What kind of pictures did you take with the camera? First try to take two pictures of something that is far (the landscape).

Answer (score 0):

I had same problems while stitching two images, 
You can change match_conf (as it is mentioned in error) or pano confidance treshold which is used for eliminate irrevelant matches via compairing their confidance with PanoConfidenceThresh. 
It could be help to try stitching with more images.